# Unable to switch tabs with Selenium in headless mode

Tags: c#, selenium, headless

Using C#/Selenium in headless mode
Now this code works fine in normal mode but times out in headless mode on line 2

```
_driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles[1]);
tUrl = _driver.Url;
_driver.Close();
_driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles[0]);
```

Any ideas why please?

This is the initialisation code

```
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("disable-browser-side-navigation");
    options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.AddArgument("ignore-ssl-errors");
    options.AddArgument("disable-popup-blocking");
    options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
    options.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
    options.AddArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", _downloadPath);
    if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        options.AddArguments("headless");
    options.AddArguments("disable-gpu");
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
    _driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I am running the tests on my own PC (Windows 10) in Chrome 102 and ChromeDriver 102 to match

Comment: It times out when executing `tUrl = _driver.Url;`?

Comment: Hi Greg, I know, I was hoping someone could explain why

Comment: Can you add the code that initializes the web driver? Also, which version of driver and browser are you using? When running in headless mode, is it running on another server or your machine?

Comment: Greg, I have updated the original question for you.